# I need to deploy a web aspx application which use Word library on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, ms-word, ms-office

I need to deploy a application written in ASPX 2.0 which uses Word library.

In visual studio this library works as expected, it generates the word
documents.

When I deploy it is on IIS, the daemon doesn't recognize Word library(or it
can't access it).

I need a fast solution to run this application to IIS 7.5.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot use Word on the server reliable. Possible solution: Use a (commercial) library like [**Aspose.Words**](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx) or [**Spire.Doc**](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/word-for-net-introduce.html).

Comment: Is Word installed on the server?

Comment: I cannot use Word on server reliable or I cannot use Word on server?

Comment: Yes, Word is installed on the server. Temporary the server is on the same machine with development machine. If I run the application from visual studio, everything works...